# Redirecting after adding multiple items to cart

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have successfully added this code to my functions.php, and it works - to great relief.

Here is a URL of it in action: https://www.bagnboxman.co.uk/?add-to-cart=207,7488,39439,939,393,395,396,411,1012,503

I would dearly love to redirect to the cart contents on loading this, so that a customer does not see a green wall of text "you have successfully added xyz to your cart"

Is this possible? How would I do this?

This is the code in question:

```
    // adds support for multi add to cart for 3rd party cart plugin
function woocommerce_maybe_add_multiple_products_to_cart() {
    // Make sure WC is installed, and add-to-cart qauery arg exists, and contains at least one comma.
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Form_Handler' ) || empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) || false === strpos( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'], ',' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove WooCommerce's hook, as it's useless (doesn't handle multiple products).
    remove_action( 'wp_loaded', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'add_to_cart_action' ), 20 );

    $product_ids = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );
    $count       = count( $product_ids );
    $number      = 0;

    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
        if ( ++$number === $count ) {
            // Ok, final item, let's send it back to woocommerce's add_to_cart_action method for handling.
            $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] = $product_id;

            return WC_Form_Handler::add_to_cart_action();
        }

        $product_id        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $product_id ) );
        $was_added_to_cart = false;

        $adding_to_cart    = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if ( ! $adding_to_cart ) {
            continue;
        }

        // only works for simple atm
        if ( $adding_to_cart->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {

            // quantity applies to all products atm
            $quantity          = empty( $_REQUEST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount( $_REQUEST['quantity'] );
            $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );

            if ( $passed_validation && false !== WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) ) {
                wc_add_to_cart_message( array( $product_id => $quantity ), true );
            }

        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'woocommerce_maybe_add_multiple_products_to_cart', 15 );
```